# every compact normal operator can be represented by product of unitary operator and compact positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Could anyone show that every compact normal operator can be represented by commutative product of unitary operator and compact positive operator? I mean if $T$ is a compact normal operator, then there exists a compact positive operator $A$ and unitary operator $B$ such that $T=AB=BA$. Are these operators uniquely determined?

Answer (score -1):

The key here that every compact normal operator $T$ on any complex Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ is diagonalizable *(see e.g. "Introduction to Hilbert Space" by Berberian, 1976)* so there exists an orthonormal system $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathcal H$ and a complex null sequence $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $|\tau_n|\geq |\tau_{n+1}|$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and

$$
T=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau_n\langle e_n,\cdot\rangle e_n.
$$

Now $A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\tau_n|\langle e_n,\cdot\rangle e_n=|T|$ is the positive-semidefinite *(obvious)* compact operator we are looking for. The compactness of $A$ can be shown e.g. by showing $A$ is the limit of the norm-convergent sequence of the finite-rank operators $(\sum_{n=1}^k|\tau_n|\langle e_n,\cdot\rangle e_n)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ **or** by using the following argumentation:

$$
|T|\text{ compact }\Leftrightarrow |T|^\dagger |T|=|T|^2=T^\dagger T\text{ compact }\Leftrightarrow T\text{ compact}
$$

The unitary operator $B$ now somehow has to transform the $\tau_n$ into their absolute value. As unitary operators are strongly connected to orthonormal bases, we extend $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ to an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in J}$ of $\mathcal H$ with $\mathbb N\subseteq J$. Define $I:=\lbrace n\in\mathbb N\,|\,\tau_n\neq 0\rbrace$ and the operator $B$ via

$$
Be_n:=\begin{cases} \frac{\tau_n}{|\tau_n|}e_n & \text{if }n\in I \\ e_n & \text{if }n\in J\,\backslash \,I \end{cases}
$$

and its linear and continous extension onto all of $\mathcal H$. Observe that

$$
\Big\langle \frac{\tau_j}{|\tau_j|}e_j,\frac{\tau_k}{|\tau_k|}e_k\Big\rangle=\delta_{jk}
$$

for all $j,k\in I$ so $B$ maps $(e_n)_{n\in J}$ to an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal H$ and thus is unitary. With this it is easy to see that $T=BA$ and $BAB^\dagger =A$ (where the latter obviously equals $BA=AB$).

For your last question, note that $A$ and $B$ are not unique as the orthonormal system $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ belonging to $T$ is not uniquely determined. For this one may consider $(e^{i\varphi}e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ for any $\varphi\in(0,2\pi)$, this still is an orthonormal system and satisfies the above decomposition of $T$. For something more concrete one may choose $T=A=0$ so $B$ can be literally any unitary operator so satisfies the required properties.